# Is a virtualenv required for making a new sysadmin user after installing ckan from package?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ckan, system-administration

I just installed ckan from package on my local machine. How can I create a new sysadmin user for my instance? How can the paster commands be run without a virtual environment. The docs did not state the requirement of a virtual env for installing ckan from package.
Also when I run the following command:

```
paster sysadmin add seanh -c /etc/ckan/default/production.ini
```

The terminal asks me to get python-pastescript. And when I execute the command "`sudo apt-get install python-pastescript`", I get the following result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
```

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-pastescript : Depends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed or
                               python-distribute
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Help needed please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you [installed CKAN from package](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html) I believe you need to use `sudo ckan` instead of `paster` in all paster commands.

e.g.

```
sudo ckan sysadmin add seanh -c /etc/ckan/default/production.ini
```